# Delete a letter forward by Ctrl + D does not work in RubyMine

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

I'm using macOS Mojave & RubyMine 2019.1 .

In my Mac, `Ctrl + D` always deletes the letter on the right of the caret.
In RubyMine, `Ctrl + D` is by default set to debugging, so I deleted the config.
However, deleting a letter by `Ctrl + D` does not work even after that. I made sure there are no assignments to the key.

What is wrong wrong about my setting?

Comment: If there are no assignments to the key... then there are no assignments to the key. Assign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut from the **Debug** action and add it to the **Delete** action instead:

[image: Delete]

Comment: This worked! I thought deleting by Ctrl + D is something like default behavior of macOS. Thank you!

Comment: it is default behavior but intelliJ is a windows-first application and thus you have weird defaults shortcuts as well as Fn keys being used